# Flask Tutorial __init__.py content

Tags: python, flask

I'm a beginner in Python and flask. I am going through the Flask tutorial up to [Blog Blueprint](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/tutorial/blog/) section.

I would like to know the meaning of `app = ...`
int the following code:

```
def create_app():
    app = ...
    # existing code omitted

    from . import blog
    app.register_blueprint(blog.bp)
    app.add_url_rule('/', endpoint='index')

    return app
```

Comment: There should be something like `app = Flask(__name__)` but unintentionally (I guess) they made it valid Python code. `...` is an `Ellipsis` object.

Answer (score 1):

In a real Flask application `...` would be replaced by a call to the `Flask` constructor, with the desired configurations.

Check this example on how to initialize a Flask app: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/tutorial/factory/

> ```
> def create_app(test_config=None):
>    # create and configure the app
>    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
>    app.config.from_mapping(
>        SECRET_KEY='dev',
>        DATABASE=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'flaskr.sqlite'),
>    )
>
>    if test_config is None:
>        # load the instance config, if it exists, when not testing
>        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
>    else:
>        # load the test config if passed in
>        app.config.from_mapping(test_config)
>
>    # ensure the instance folder exists
>    try:
>        os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
>    except OSError:
>        pass
>
>    # a simple page that says hello
>    @app.route('/hello')
>    def hello():
>        return 'Hello, World!'
>
>    return app
> ```